# the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\sin(1+\frac{x}{n})}$ converges uniformly in $[-a,a]$

Tags: analysis

I have to show that the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\sin(1+\frac{x}{n})}$ converges uniformly in $[-a,a], a>0$.
$$$$
That's what I have tried:

$w_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \sin1 \cos(\frac{x}{n})+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \cos1 \sin(\frac{x}{n})=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \sin1 (\cos(\frac{x}{n})+1-1)+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \cos1 \sin(\frac{x}{n})= \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \sin1 (\cos(\frac{x}{n})-1)+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \sin1 +\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}  \cos1 \sin(\frac{x}{n})=\sin1 \cdot g_n(x)+ \cos1 \cdot  f_n(x)+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \sin1 $ .

We set $d_n(x)=w_n-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \sin1=\sin1 \cdot g_n(x)+ \cos1 \cdot  f_n(x)$

$|g_n(x)|=|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}(\cos(\frac{x}{n})-1)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} (\cos(\frac{x}{n})-1) (\cos(\frac{x}{n})+1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(\sin^2(\frac{x}{n})) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \frac{x^2}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \frac{a^2}{n^2}=\frac{a^2}{n^{\frac{5}{2}}}$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^2}{n^{\frac{5}{2}}}< +\infty$.

$|f_n(x)|=|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \sin(\frac{x}{n})| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{x}{n} \leq \frac{a}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}< +\infty$.

Also,from Dirichlet's test,we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges,let $b:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$

Therefore,we have $d_n(x) \leq \sin1 \frac{a^2}{n^{\frac{5}{2}}}+ \cos1  \frac{a}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin1 \frac{a^2}{n^{\frac{5}{2}}}+ \cos1  \frac{a}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ converges,as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^2}{n^{\frac{5}{2}}}$ converges  and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ converges too.

So, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} d_n(x)$ converges uniformly to a $s(x)$.
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} d_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (w_n-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \sin1)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} w_n-b \overset{uniformly}{=}s(x) \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} w_n=b+s(x):=q(x):[-a,a] $

So,the series converges uniformly to $q(x)$.

Could you tell me if it is right?

Answer (score -1):

*Hint* You may use Dirichlet's criterion, since $\sin (xn^{-1})$ is eventually decreasing in $[0,M]$ and $1-\cos (xn^{-1})$ is eventually decreasing in $[0,M]$ too, and both go uniformly to zero, and $$\sum_{n\geqslant 1} (-1)^{n}n^{-1/2}$$ converges.

Comment: I haven't understood it.. Do I use Dirichlet's criterion,because $b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ and is  decreasing and the partial sum $s=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^k \sin1 \cos(\frac{x}{k})$ is bounded??If yes, why is the partial sum bounded?

Comment: @evinda Re-read what I wrote. Dirichlet's criterion wants a decreasing sequence $a_n(x)$ that goes monotonically to zero, and a sequence of functions whose sum is bounded, $b_n(x)$. I took $a_n(x)=\sin(xn^{-1}),1-\cos(xn^{-1})$ and $b_n(x)=(-1)^n n^{-1/2}$.

Comment: I edited my post...Could you tell me if it is better now?

Comment: I cannot understand why this was downvoted.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Excellent proof. Don't worry i upvoted it